# How to make sub-branch the master branch?

Tags: git

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570590/make-git-branch-the-master-branch) answer, but I'm unsure of what the answerer meant by using `git branch -f ..` in order to complete the task.

I have three branches, my `master` branch has a bunch of files that I don't want sticking around, which I know they will if I use merge. I somewhat understand deleting a branch, but can I really do that to the `master` branch?

I know there is a probably simple solution to the problem, but could someone explain what each git command is doing? It would help a fair bit.

Question: How can I `merge` my `sub-branch` into the master while only keeping the files from the `sub-branch` and none from the `master` whilst keeping my `sub-branch`?

Comment: @AlessandroVendruscolo Oops. I guess I forgot to reiterate properly. I think that will help a bit. I'm trying to figure out the best way to get my sub-branch to become my new master branch without losing my sub-branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout the sub-branch, delete master branch, checkout a copy of your sub-branch and name it master.

```
git checkout sub-branch
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
```

Comment: So deleting master doesn't have any implications? And this is the best way to do it?

Comment: This depends on wither your repo is pushed online or not, if it is it might cause problems for other users, if it's just a local repo, it has 0 implications, you don't even have to work on master branch at all, it's just a name.

Comment: Oh. I guess when so many people always referred to master versus branches, I always thought of it as some superior being or whatnot. Could you also explain what git branch -f is doing? I'm looking at the docs, but I don't quite get it.

Comment: I have never used it, doesn't make much sense to me either.

Comment: @OneOnOne Okay. Well, thank you for easing my mind about deleting the master.